# Web pages indexed issue with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, seo

when i do the SEO for my Wordpress website,i generate the sitemap and submit it on search console,161 url generate in sitemap but when result comes of sitemap it only indexed 1 page ,what is this problem and how can i solve this

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is really not about programming ...

Answer (score 0):

Google Automatically Index all pages with time if you have submitted the sitemap.
Also if you want to do SEO. You must have SEO Friendly URLS

Comment: my all url are seo friendly but it does not show indexing on serach console

Comment: but when i submit sitemap on search console,it shows only one page indexed